# save dates in string format, without time and minutes

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am working with `mat-datepicker` and moment, I would like to save the selected date in string format and that is '`DD/MM/YYY'` => `01/07/2019`, then I can read that date with `mat-datepicker`, now if this does not it is possible, then I could save the date in string with ISO format, the problem is that when I select the date and then print it in console or save, this date is in the form Object type of moment, as that could happen automatically to the selected the date

Comment: can you make small demo of code

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-local-date

Answer (score 0):

.html code:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Input & change events"
         (dateChange)="addEvent('change', $event)">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

{{localdate}}

.ts code:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {MatDatepickerInputEvent} from '@angular/material/datepicker';

@Component({
  selector: 'datepicker-events-example',
  templateUrl: 'datepicker-events-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['datepicker-events-example.css'],
})
export class DatepickerEventsExample {

  public localdate;
  addEvent(type: string, event: MatDatepickerInputEvent<Date>) {
    this.localdate = (`${event.value}`);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please consider documenting what you've done to solve OP's problem.

Comment: @Luis Ruiz Figueroa   check the demo code on this link . https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-local-date

Comment: if that was the first thing I did, but for some reason the value returned in my app is an object and not a string.